# need to trigger bootstrap grid breakpoint based on min-width of a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have contents of a webpage within a Bootstrap grid.  One div (divDesktopDiv) is displayed in desktop view and is replaced by another div in mobile view (divMobileDiv).

Something about my current implementation causes the divDesktopDiv to overflow into the adjacent div before the grid snaps into the mobile view to display divMobileDiv.

Is there a way I can set some type of min-width attr on divDesktopDiv which will force Bootstrap to render the next breakpoint view when the min-width attr on that div gets hit? I already explicitly tried setting min-width on the div but it doesn't trigger the next breakpoint.  It simply keeps that div as min-width while shrinking the rest of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Bootstrap documentation for responsive breakpoints](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints). Essentially, you can change the @media query's breakpoints so that grid snaps into mobile view before they overlap. Just change the pixels to a higher or lower number based on need.